# Opencv BFMatcher for multiple images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to perform Brute Force SIFT features matching in Python with opencv.

I found the following code on the opencv documentation.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.SIFT()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# BFMatcher with default params
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

# cv2.drawMatchesKnn expects list of lists as matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

However, this code is only for two images. I tried feeding a list of descriptors but it doesn't seem to work. How can I perform the matching of multiple database images at once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BFMatcher only works for two descriptors at a time. If you check out the documentation here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

> Brute-Force matcher is simple.
>   It takes the descriptor of one feature in first set and is matched
>   with all other features in second set using some distance calculation.
>   And the closest one is returned.

I am quite unsure with what you mean by multiple descriptors. However, I know you can take the descriptor from image1 matching with image2. Then, match image1 with image3. Lastly,image2 with image3. Matching multiple images' descriptors needs to be done manually.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to rank these matches ?

Comment: @Lilo You need to sort them by ascending order (the lower distance the better). Just do:
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda match: match.distance)